# fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the work ng tree

Tags: git

I'm a complete newbie with git, I'm just following instructions.  I compiled a piece of software and the dev has updated it and so I'm trying to get onto the latest version to re-compile.

I'm trying to do:

```
git init
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

A few weeks ago it did work the first time I tried to upgrade but now its giving me that error in the title.

Tried deleting the source files and doing a new git fetch but that doesn't work either.

OS is raspbian-lite jessie.

Comment: You need to run `git init` only once, to create the Git repository. It doesn't harm to run it again in a repo but it doesn't help either.

Comment: You have to clone the dev's repository. With ``git init` you are creating a new one. If you have cloned it and you want to update you should use `git pull`

Comment: @Scalextrix do you run these commands inside the local Git repository? Show the output of `git remote -v`.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

First off do the github tutorial :D

https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

if you deleted the LOCAL repository you need to:

- git init (initialize repository)
- git clone (get the repo to your computer)
- git pull (update later if you have it)

Comment: Thanks, I will read the tutorial, I just didnt have time, git pull seems to have done the trick